# How to create multiple change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html select and a add button. If any one click on add button then an html select create same class, name. My problem is if I change first html select then change function work properly but if I change created html select then change function don’t work. Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks. Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>the title</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','.name',function(){
        calculateSum();
    });

    $(document).on('click','.del',function(){
        calculateSum();
    });
});


          function calculateSum() {
          $.post(
             "data.php",
             $(".name").serialize(),
                 function(data) {
                $('#stage1').html(data);
             }
          );
      }


   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
/*
This script is identical to the above JavaScript function.
*/
var ct = 1;

function new_link()
{
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;

    // link to delete extended form elements
    var delLink = '<div class="del" style="text-align:right;margin-top:-20px"><a href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';

    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;

    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);

}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId)
{
    d = document;

    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);

    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');

    parentEle.removeChild(ele);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="stage1" style="background-color:blue; color: white">
          STAGE - 1
   </div>

<form id="testform">
<div id="newlink">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><p>Fruit:</p></td>
 <td>
     <select class="name" name="name[]">
         <option>Apple</option>
         <option>Mango</option>
         <option>Orange</option>
         <option>Banana</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="javascript:new_link()"/>
</form>
    <div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
        <table>
        <tr>
 <td><p>Fruit:</p></td>
 <td>
     <select class="name" name="name[]">
         <option>Apple</option>
         <option>Mango</option>
         <option>Orange</option>
         <option>Banana</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$fruit=$_REQUEST["name"];
$n = count($fruit);


for($i=0;$i<$n; $i++)
{
    echo $fruit[$i]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't get it. - Why are you mixing jQuery with plain Javascript in the first place? - An id attribute must not start with a numeric character. - you are not creating a new select anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery FAQ docs have a good description of your situation.

http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_doesn.27t_an_event_work_on_a_new_element_I.27ve_created.3F

You need to use event delegation in order to bind events to future elements that don't exists when the code is run.

Use `on()` method and bind the event to an element that will always exist or to the document itself.

```
$(document).on('change','.name', function(){

/* your code here*/
})
```

API Reference :  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Can you please, tell me how to apply this function for two element. please, see my update code. Only change function work properly. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways around this, but since you're using jQuery, the easiest way would be using `.on('change','selector',[function]);` rather then binding the `change` listener directly. The best approach, of course, would be `.delegate`, or -in *"pure"* JS:

```
document.body.addEventListener('change',function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select' && target.className.match(/\bname\b/))
    {
        theActualHandler.apply(target,[e]);//calls the actual handler, this will point to the changed element, and the event object is passed as an argument.
    }
},false);
```

Delegating the event means that you're listening for an event to happen, somewhere in the DOM. When it happens, you can check if that event is headed for an element that meats certain criteria: in this case it's a `select` element, that has a class called `name`. From there on end, it's just a simple matter of calling the actual handler. Using `.apply` allows you to set the context to the element that was changed *and* pass the event object to that same function. That function, then, will act exactly like it would when you bind the handler directly. 
For now, though, jQuery's `.delegate` does, pretty much, the same thing and will be more familiar, so I'd recommend you use that :)

Links:

- [jQuery's delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
- [jQuery's on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [An introduction to the concepts of event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)